# Fuzzy matching of user generated dataset to stored datasets

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service

I have stored workflows. They're trees with decision points.  Basically every point in the data is a command issued. Adding it all up is a workflow to build something from the commands.

I'm trying to use azure ml to take a partially completed workflow from a user and match it against these stored workflows.

Adding to the difficulty is that I'm never sure when the user has started or stopped a workflow so it's always a Time preference match that is never perfect.

Despite days of searching I can't find any information on canned algorithms that do this type of pattern matching.

Can someone suggest where I might find some information on taking a data series (not numeric) and match that to a tree graph of similar values in real time?

Comment: This is an interesting question but can you provide some simple sample data an expected results.  I'm guessing this would look something like: featurize the steps of the process, train a model on a test set which you have labelled, then validate it.  This would be a supervised approach.  You could also try an unsupervised approach e.g. clustering.  You probably need help from a data scientist, you could try the stackoverflow Data Science group.

Comment: Rows of: ProdictId, VersionId, Command, datetimr.  The stored workflows also have parentid to get the ordering and branching.  I need to pattern match the former into the later with a probability. I can't find anything that pattern matches arrays other than image matching which is only indirectly relevant but seemed like a valid approach to bitmap them and use azure image matching to do it... Overkill I'm sure and would love a simpler way.

Comment: Have a look through the Cortana gallery: https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/

Comment: I have. Nothing seems to do what I need. The closest doesn't do windowing.